# why the async Task<TResult> always return empty value

Tags: c#

I want to do something in a for loop and use 'await Task.Delay()'.
But I always go the empty, it should return 10.

```
public class Test {
    public async Task<int> test() {
        int sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("start loop");
            sum++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("finish loop");
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

//Main

```
Test test = new Test()
var test1 = test.test().Result;
```

Comment: Do you wait for it before checking/printing value?

Comment: What is empty?  I don't understand.  Do you mean it returns Zero?  Also how would it get to 55, the math doesn't add up.

Comment: Please show how you call this, I guess you don't wait for the task to complete. Plus the expected result of your code is 10, not 55. If you want 55 change `sum++;` to `sum += i;`

Comment: @RenéVogt That would still only add to 45.

Comment: @hvd right, it's `i < 10`... OP edited anyway.

Comment: sorry, I just make a sample.
I could't get the return from 'sum', I will get the empty, I'm not sure it's null or what.

Comment: I have no idea what "get the empty" means. As asked already, can you show actual code that calls this method, that demonstrates how you aren't getting the result you expect?

Comment: @LittleTin Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce your error. At least provide an example of how you call that method and how you try to get the return value. (Note that this method returns a `Task<int>`, not an `int`).

Comment: @LittleTin Just do this: `var result = test().Result;`   Now you should wait 10 seconds and get your result.

Comment: I use 'test().Result' to call this.

Comment: @FCin That would cause a deadlock in normal situations.

Comment: @LittleTin And now you changed your expected result from 10 to 9. Why? You go through the loop 10 times. Your `sum` starts at 0 and increments each time you go through the loop. How do you end up at 9?

Comment: I had update the code, when I run it, it will show "stat loop", but won't do anything, after 1 second, thread will finish.

Comment: @LittleTin the last edit was wrong, it's 10, not 9. And it works for me. Last try: provide code so that we can reproduce it. `test().Result` gives 10 after 10 seconds (thoug hvd is right that this might dead lock with certain synchronization contexts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that waiting for `test().Result` causes a dead lock. The reason is that this line

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

returns the execution flow to the caller, which then calls `test().Result` to wait for the task to complete. So your main thread is blocking.

The `await` in the above line tries to resume execution of `test` when `Task.Delay()` finishes. But per default it tries to resume this execution on your calling thread. Yes, the thread that is currently blocked because it waits for `Result`.

One solution maybe to change the line to:

```
await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This causes `await` to no longer try to resume on the original thread but any other. This way you avoid the dead lock and your program should continue.

Comment: thanks! but It means I need to add 'ConfigureAwait(false)' for each Task.Delay, right?

Comment: @LittleTin I guess the details depend on your real code. I suppose it's enough to append it to the first `await`ed call in `test()`, because after that you're on a different thread already.

Answer (score 0):

`Await` ensures the rest of the code in the current async method doesn't execute until after the awaited completes. 
in a console app, there is no specialized SynchronizationContext;that means your continuations will run on Thread Pool threads.the `Test` method returns control to `Main`, which just continues executing .

```
        var t = new Test();
        t.test().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(t.test().Result);//output is 10
```